# how to write css style in Html

Tags: html, css

how to write css style in Html? without using class
For example

```
    <html><p padding-top=55; color = red;'>Title"</p></html>
```

Comment: You have hundreds of resources to help you with basic CSS styles. Please read them

Comment: You can use the `style` attribute.  Though, honestly, you should really keep your markup and your styling separated.

Comment: `<p style="color: red; padding-top: 55px">Test</p>` - This is very simple and could be learned after minimal research.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has done no research on their own.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to add a style attribute. The value is just css. You must also define the units used with measurements. In this example I've used pixels (px) :

```
<p style="padding-top: 55px; color: red;">Title</p>
```

I've also taken the liberty of stripping out the single and double quote which I'm guessing aren't meant to be there?

On a more general note, you don't want to be adding inline styles. You want to define your styles in a separate css file so everything is in one place, easily maintainable, and you can reuse styles. Also, if you wanted a complete overhaul you can just swap out the css file with another one without having to worry about your inline styles.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use the `style` tag. and all css values goes as value for that tag (`style`). and there are lot of property when you specify you have to specify the value is as `%` or `px`.  and padding is one of them. and as these all are as value of `style` tag so u can not use `=` so define the value of `css` property.  you have to use `:`.

Finally conclusion is that -

> Its not teaching-learning platform.  `Stackoverflow` is for problem resolution.. so better to go and learn HTML and CSS

```
<html>
 <head>     </head>
 <body>
  <p style="padding-top:55px; color:red;">Title</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/a90x3y4m/